# making values in list of dictionaries lowercase in python

Tags: python-3.x

[Picture of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KncYk.png)So, I'm making this program where you take a file and break it down and take out specific parts that you need and add those values to a dictionary and then append that dictionary into a list. After you do that you search through that list of dictionaries you have and pull out certain values based off the information the user provides. So far I have everything done but now I have to make everything in that list of dictionaries lowercase but the list of dictionaries is full of different value types and I don't know how to go about doing this.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os.path

def get_file_name(file_name):
    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        return file_name
    else:
        file_name = input('Please enter a file name: ')
        get_file_name(file_name)

def search_counties(new_list):
    c = [line.strip(',') for line in new_list]
    texts = [[word.lower() for word in text.split(',')] for text in c]
    print(c)
    county = input('Search: ')
    county.lower()
    while county not in ['q', 'quit']:
        for row in new_list:
            county_name, county_count, county_percent, county_median = row.split(',')

            if county == county_name:
                pass





    '''
    while that search term is not q or quit enter a loop
        1. iterate over your counties parameter to see if any of the county's names match the search term
            ** You may need to convert your search term to lowercase and compare it to the county name converted to lowercase
        2. if you find a match then call print_county and pass it your county dict
        3. ask the user for another search term (gives the user a chance to search again or q or quit to exit)
    '''

def print_highest_data(counties):
    # This function is complete
    # since we sorted our list of counties in main() all we have to do here is call print_county and pass it the last county dict in our list
    print_county(counties[-1])


def print_lowest_data(counties):
    print_county(counties[0])
    # same as above, except we call print_county and pass it the first county dict in our list


def print_county(county):
    # This function is complete 
    # if you use different keys in your dicts then you'll need to change them below
    print('Name: %s' % county['name'])
    print('Percentage: %.2f%%' % county['percent'])
    print('Children in Poverty: {:,}'.format(county['count']))
    print('Household Income: ${:,}'.format(county['income']))
    print()

def main():

    new_list=[]
    file_name = input('Please enter a file name: ')
    file = get_file_name(file_name)
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    first_line = True
    for row in file:
        if first_line == True:
            first_line = False
            continue
        dictionary={}
        dictionary['name']= str(row[193:238])
        dictionary['count']= int(row[50:57])
        dictionary['percent']= float(row[76:80])
        dictionary['income']= int(row[134:139])
        new_list.append(dictionary)
    file.close()
    new_list = sorted(new_list, key=lambda x: x['percent'])
    print_highest_data(new_list)
    print_lowest_data(new_list)
    search_counties(new_list)









    # prompt for the filename

    # check to make sure file exists, if it doesn't prompt again

    # create an empty list to contain all of the contains

    ''' 
    iterate over each line in the file (**you may need to skip the first line if it contains a header)
         For each line parse out the children count, percentage of children in poverty, median income, and county name
         **For help parsing, view the census.gov page (http://www.census.gov//did/www/saipe/data/statecounty/data/2014.html)
         Add those four values to a dict (this dict will represent the county)
         append that dict to your list
    '''

    '''
    once you leave your for loop sort the counties by percentage
    **see the lab instructions for guidance on how to sort the dict by a particular value
    '''

    # call print_highest_data and pass it your list of counties as a parameter

    # call print_lowest_data and pass it your list of counties as a parameter

    # call search_counties and pass it your list of counties as a parameter




# if we are running this script then call the main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the file and the expected output.

Comment: By different value types can we assume you mean primitives like int and strings?  Also do you need to lowercase the keys and values or just the values?

Comment: Yea the list is made up of int, str, and floats. And I need the values to be lower case because the plan is to have the user enter in a county name and to have the program search through the list of dictionaries and pull out the dictionary that has the same county name the user inputs and print out the values of that dictionary.

Comment: Please enter a file name: est14_sc.txt
Name: Allendale County
Percentage: 48.70%
Children in Poverty: 912
Household Income: $25,530

Name: York County
Percentage: 19.00%
Children in Poverty: 11,366
Household Income: $54,196

Search: Horry
Name: Horry County
Percentage: 29.90%
Children in Poverty: 16,938
Household Income: $42,830

Search: Georgetown
Name: Georgetown County
Percentage: 31.60%
Children in Poverty: 3,781
Household Income: $44,283

Search: Cobb
Search: quit

Comment: ^this is an example of how the output should look

Comment: @TheChosenOne please edit your question to include the example file. It doesn't format properly in a comment. Also, please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).